# how to create a search form in php and mysql with pagination?

Tags: php, mysql, search, post

I am trying to create a search form with php and mysql and do a pagination

so i have a form that looks like this:

```
<form action="search_results.php" method="post">
                        <select name="cat" id="cat">
                            <option>Select Category</option>
                            <?php
                            foreach($categories as $category) {
                            echo "<option value=\"{$category -> name}\">{$category -> name}</option>";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                        <select name="sub-cat" id="sub-cat">
                            <option>Select Sub Category</option>
                        </select>
                        <label>Price Range</label>
                        <input type="text" name="from" placeholder="From" />
                        <input type="text" name="to" placeholder="To" />
                        <input type="submit" value="" name="submit" />
                    </form>
```

my problem is that i get the first page in the search_result.php

and when i try to go to the second page the $_POST['submit'] wouldn't be set because it didn't get any submit

anybody has an idea how to solve this issue

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use GET in this case for the form and for the subsequent pagination links for the very reason that you specified.

POST is better used as a one off action where GET is a request for resources which can be filtered and hacked.

```
search_results.php?cat=1&sub-cat=2&page=2

search_results.php?cat=1&sub-cat=2&page=3

search_results.php?cat=1&sub-cat=2&page=4

search_results.php?cat=1&sub-cat=2&page=5
```

Comment: i was trying to avoid using get so from what you are saying there is no other way to get it with out $_GET

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to generate "next" and "previous" URLs that have the search information in the query string, and then have the receiving page read them from $_GET instead of $_POST. The $_GET array works exactly like the $_POST array, just for variables that were passed in the URL.

Another option would be to create a form where the search information is present in hidden fields, and use javascript to cause the "next" and "previous" links to change the value for the page to get, and then submit the form. This would allow you to use the exact same POST-based code you're using now, though it prevents users from bookmarking search pages and may have other unintended effects.

Comment: Thanks a lot but is there an example if you don't mind because i haven't used this JavaScript based next and previous

Comment: The basic command is `document.getElementById('YourFormId').submit()`. If you search the web for "javascript form submit" you'll find many tutorials showing it in context.